# FindNode method TreeView with Forward Slash in Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I have a tree view control. The code below is used to find the specific parent node.

```
TreeView AllProductsTreeView;

TreeNode nodeFound = AllProductsTreeView.FindNode("AAA/Sensors");
```

**AAA** - Category

**Sensors** - Sub Category

This works fine but the issue occurs when a subcategory value contains a forward slash.

```
TreeView AllProductsTreeView;

TreeNode nodeFound = AllProductsTreeView.FindNode("AAA/Sensors/Energy");
```

**AAA** - Category

**Sensors/Energy**- Sub Category

In above situation it returns a null value for nodeFound object.

How can I use find node method with a forward slash to find the subcategory.

Thanks in  Advance!

Answer (score 2):

The character "/" has a special functionality for `FindNode` (main/child node differentiation) and there seems to not be any way to avoid it. One option would be not using this character for node names at all. If you don't want to change the names, you can complement the in-built functionality with a custom one, as shown in the code below:

```
string nodePath = "AAA/Sensors/Energy";
TreeNode nodeFound = null;
string[] temp = nodePath.Split('/');
if (temp.Length > 2)
{
    //More than one "/"
    TreeNode mainNode = AllProductsTreeView.FindNode(temp[0]);
    string childPath = nodePath.Substring(temp[0].Length + 1, nodePath.Length - temp[0].Length - 1);
    foreach (TreeNode childNode in mainNode.ChildNodes)
    {
        if (childNode.Value == childPath)
        {
            nodeFound = childNode;
            break;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    nodeFound = AllProductsTreeView.FindNode(nodePath);
}
```

As you can see, this code only relies on `FindNode` when the given name contains one "/" or less; in all the other cases, it extracts the main node name and looks through all its children by relying on the `Value` property (for which the "/" character does not trigger any special functionality).

CLARIFICATION: the code above can deal with any situation (independently upon the number of "/" in the name of the child node) which verifies any of the following structures:

```
Main_node_without_slashes/Child_node_containing_any_number_of_slashes
Main_node_without_slashes
```

In case of having main nodes including forward slashes you would have to update this code, by setting up a way to tell the code when the "/" should be understood as main-child differentiation and when as part of the name.

Comment: We cant say it has only one separator. it depends on the Database values. So its not fixed.I just told only one scenario. We don't know the values in the Database at the time of implementation:(

Comment: @Kanishka it can deal with any number of slashes; I was just explaining how it works: if the input string (nodePath) contains one slash (or none), FindNode is used directly; otherwise nodePath is divided into the first chunk (main node) and all the remaining information (assumed to be the child node). This code works fine for any situation where you have: ParentNode/Childnode_containing_as_many_slashes_as_required. Examples of acceptable input: node1/node2-part1/node2-part2/node2-part3 -> this code assumes that node1 is the main node and "node2-part1/node2-part2/node2-part3" is the child node

Comment: @Kanishka if in the example above you want node1 to be the main node and node2-part1 to be its child and node2-part2 to be the child of node2-part1, it wouldn't work: it expects one main node + one child node (including as many slashes as required). Please, understand the code, test it and confirm that works as expected. If you want to tune it up to deliver a different performance, I would help you; in any case, bear in mind that my intention when writing the code was showing you a way to face the problem (ideally, you should be the one adapting it to your specific requirements).

Comment: Thanks for the code. But as u said there is a instance where I need "node1 to be the main node and node2-part1 to be its child and node2-part2 to be the child of node2-part1". Its included in my task. That is where I'm stuck.

Comment: @Kanishka If you get something like this: node1/node2-part1/node2-part2 NOBODY can tell what does mean exactly (3 nodes or 2 nodes) without further information, so you cannot expect a computer to determine what you are not even able to do by hand. Think carefully about what you want exactly and understand the only two options you have: either removing all the "/" and avoiding problems; or clearly defining what is main/child node and relying on a code on the lines of what I propose. But better don't waste time on intending to come up with a solution for an unsolvable problem :)

Comment: Yes I am working with changing the Path separator to another value.Hope it will solve my issue.Update you once it is done. BDW thanks for your effort.

Comment: @Kanishka no problem. Although depending upon the way you are using to call this function, it might acceptable to keep the "/"s; that is, if you provide the main-node/child-nodes information (what shouldn't be too difficult), you might easily adapt the proposed function. I look forward to your update.