# C# - Populate TreeView from Forward Slash String

Tags: c#, treeview

> Sport/Football/Team/Pl. Chris Roberts
>
> Sport/Football/Team/E2/sharks
>
> Sport/Football/Team/B3/A2/static
>
> Sport/Football/Team/E2/wood
>
> Sport/Football/Team/Pl. Paul Griffith

I get from my My Two-Dimensional `Array [i,3]` several strings like above.
How is it possible to populate a TreeView without duplicated entries?
Need it for a desktop application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FindNode method TreeView with Forward Slash in Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119834/findnode-method-treeview-with-forward-slash-in-value)

Comment: Spezified my Question: I need it for a Desktop Application. (Systems.Windows.Forms.TreeView)